# Ruby statistical gem

Tags: ruby, statistics

What Ruby gems are there that can perform data processing?

Comment: Question is proposed to be closed. See: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213/list-of-candidate-questions-to-be-closed

Comment: I think this question should be retained. The question would be suitable for stackoverflow. However, I think it's also suitable here on Stats.SE. Stats.SE has many existing questions regarding statistical software and implementation. Also, the question specifically concerns statistics.

Comment: This site (and this question) should have the following tags: [programming-languages] [ruby] [libraries]. With [r] being the top tag at XV, I think these are all appropriate.

Comment: This is a very important and good question.

Answer (score 9):

There are 3 ways that I know of to access R from Ruby:

- [RinRuby](https://sites.google.com/a/ddahl.org/rinruby-users/)
- [RSRuby](https://github.com/alexgutteridge/rsruby)
- Rserve through the [Rserve-Ruby-Client](https://github.com/clbustos/Rserve-Ruby-client)

RinRuby is the slowest, RSRuby is the fastest and Rserve is closer to RSRuby in performance. RSRuby however is quite platform specific and you need to compile R with the sharelib option. Rserve-Ruby-Client is easier in that aspect since Rserve provides a TCP socket server for you to send commands to R interpreter.

AFAIK all 3 are unfortunately not as well documented for beginners. Rserve-Ruby-Client is pretty active, the other 2 are less so.

Answer (score 4):

Srikant is probably right that this would get better answers at stack overflow, but here's a quick answer anyway:

- **Rubygsl** provides an interface to the GNU Scientific Library.
- **RSRuby** provides a way to invoke R commands through Ruby

Answer (score 4):

[statsample](http://ruby-statsample.rubyforge.org/) appears to be the gem you are looking for. It has converters to and from various datasources and a suite of functions for statistical analysis.

Answer (score 0):

[DescriptiveStatistics](https://github.com/thirtysixthspan/descriptive_statistics) adds methods to the Enumerable module to allow easy calculation of basic descriptive statistics of Numeric sample data in collections that have included Enumerable such as Array, Hash, Set, and Range. The statistics that can be calculated are:

```
Number
Sum
Mean
Median
Mode
Variance
Standard Deviation
Percentile
Percentile Rank
Descriptive Statistics
Quartiles
```